# Error displaying GeoJSON shapes with Flubber.js in Svelte

Tags: javascript, json, svg, svelte

**UPDATE**: I have included a [REPL with the code and data here](https://svelte.dev/repl/955944ab7adc427a8a8c6e3c03fec4d7?version=4.0.0).

I am trying to use Svelte and Flubber to recreate the [demo example](https://github.com/veltman/flubber/blob/master/demos/basic-array.html) which shows morphing geojson shapes. I prefer not to use D3 and found an [example](https://svelte.dev/repl/b83cdec283504af7bd424c24357dfa76?version=3.24.0) which showed me how to interpolate using `tweened`.

My `topo.json`, containing the data, is uploaded [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/thedivtagguy/7a10e977d34b550e4b360d467961c7d1/raw/40492dcdc924ec42194dd52f7357c66ff7f8a6e7/map.topo.json).

This is what I have so far:

```html
<script>
   import { interpolate } from 'flubber';
  import { feature } from 'topojson';
  import { tweened } from 'svelte/motion';
  import * as eases from 'svelte/easing';
  import wards from '$lib/Wards/shapes/map.topo.json';

  const shape = tweened(undefined, {
    interpolate,
    easing: eases.cubicInOut,
    duration: 400,
  });

  let places = feature(wards, wards.objects.states).features.map(function (d) {
    return d.geometry.coordinates[0];
  });

  // Convert the polygon coordinates to a string format
  places = places.map(function (d) {
    return d.map(function (d) {
      return d.join(',');
    });
  });
  let selected = 0;
  $: $shape = places[selected];
</script>

{#each Object.keys(places) as key}
  <button
     class:selected="{selected === key}"
     on:click="{() => (selected = key)}"
   >
  {key}
  </button>
{/each}

<main>
   <svg viewBox="0 0 960 500">
      <path d="{$shape}"></path>
   </svg>
</main>
```

When I run this, I get the following errors in my console:

```
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected moveto path command ('M' or 'm'), "77.4618079999067…".

Uncaught TypeError: All shapes must be supplied as arrays of [x, y] points or an SVG path string (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d).
Example valid ways of supplying a shape would be:
[[0, 0], [10, 0], [10, 10]]
"M0,0 L10,0 L10,10Z"
```

What am I doing wrong? I suspect it has something to do with the interpolate function, but I am unsure what. Do I need to convert the array of points into something like a traditional SVG path (`"M0,0 L10,0 L10,10Z"` )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a REPL with the fixed code: https://svelte.dev/repl/6f98e177b5bf416e8a9c269a37b08d7d?version=4.0.0
For posterity, here's the fixed contents:

```
<script>
  import flubber from 'flubber';
  import { feature } from 'topojson';
  import { tweened } from 'svelte/motion';
  import * as eases from 'svelte/easing';
  import wards from './wards.topo.json';

  const shape = tweened(undefined, {
    interpolate: flubber.interpolate,
    easing: eases.cubicInOut,
    duration: 400,
  });

  let places = feature(wards, wards.objects.collection).features.map(function (
    d
  ) {
    return d.geometry.coordinates[0];
  });

  // for each place, // Convert the polygon coordinates to a string format
  places = places.map(function (d) {
    const points = d[0].map((p, i) => {
      const x = p[0].toFixed(4), y = p[1].toFixed(4)
      if (i == 0) return `M${x},${y}`
      return `L${x},${y}`
    });
    return points.join(" ") + "Z";
  });

  let selected = 0;
  $: $shape = s;
</script>

{#each Object.keys(places) as key}
  <button
    class:selected="{selected === key}"
    on:click="{() => (selected = key)}"
  >
    {key}
  </button>
{/each}

<main>
  <svg viewBox="77 12 2 2">
    <path d={$shape}></path>
  </svg>
</main>

<style>
  svg {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
  }

  path {
    fill: #0074d9;
  }

  button {
    margin: 0 0.5em 0 0;
  }

  .selected {
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
  }
</style>
```